# Bug in Excel-VBA IsDate()

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, date

The `IsDate()` function in Excel-VBA should recognize if a given string is/can be interpreted as a date.

But this macro:

```
Sub isdate_test()
If IsDate(Cells(1, 1)) Then
    MsgBox "Yes"
Else
    MsgBox "No"
End If
End Sub
```

recognizes for example "29.2.23" as a date. Even "50.2.21" returns "Yes". Anybody has an idea why this is happening?
`IsDate()` is quite useless for me because of this.

I forgot to mention: the date has to be read like this: DD.MM.YY

Comment: perhaps your cell reference needs to be qualified with something like `activesheet.` and `.value`

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with UK (or US) regional settings. But your entries may be being recognized as Times.  In the immediate window, type `?isDATE("50.2.21")`  If it returns `True`, then type `?cDATE("50.2.21")` to see how it is being interpreted.   If it returns `False` in the immediate window, then something is going on in your Excel cell to convert that date.  Or you are not referring to the cell/worksheet you think you are.

Answer (score 0):

The `isDate()` function includes the ability to interpter against a "Date expression".

> **date expression** -
> Any expression that can be interpreted as a date, including date literals, numbers that look like dates, strings that look like dates, and dates returned from functions. A date expression is limited to numbers or strings, in any combination, that can represent a date from January 1, 100 - December 31, 9999.
>
> Dates are stored as part of a real number. Values to the left of the
> decimal represent the date; values to the right of the decimal
> represent the time. Negative numbers represent dates prior to December
> 30, 1899.

Because `50.2.21` has 3 distinct parts, it is interpreted as a date expression. It likely believes the date to be the 21st of February, 50 (150 AD). If the value of your cell contained the text "chocolate", that would result in a "No" message box.

You can also test this in the Immediate Window. Here's an example

```
a = isDate("50/2/21")
debug.print a
True
b = isDate("Chocolate")
debug.print b
False
```

Comment: `debug.Print day("50.2.22")
 22 
debug.Print day("22.2.50")
 22  `

This behavior is quiet strange for me. Once the last number is interpreted as day and then the first number is.

Comment: Why the behavior is a problem for me?
Because I wrote a Macro, where the user has to enter a date. For example if he enters 29.2.23 (DD.MM.YY), I want the macro to quit and return an error to the user "invalid date". Therefore I don't want Excel to interprete the input differently so that it matches a date, i.e. YY.MM.DD. 
if I enter a string like "*.*.*" in a ExcelCell it always trys to interprete it as DD.MM.YY. If that is not possible the value in the cells behaves like a string an not a date.

Comment: That's not what your question says. In your case then, you want to use date literals `Any sequence of characters with a valid format that is surrounded by number signs (#). Valid formats include the date format specified by the locale settings for your code or the universal date format.`

Comment: OK, but this is still weird/unexpected behavior.
"29.2.23" isn't accepted as a date in an ExcelCell, but VBA IsDate() still returns true.

Comment: "strings that look like date" it has 3 sets of numbers, separated by a `.` so the date expression believes it to be a date.

Comment: I just did `a = IsDate("29.2.23")
debug.Print a` in the immediate window, and it came back `false`

Comment: the `.` is a time separator. also, it's complicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338025/isdate-function-returns-unexpected-results